# ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess in MVC 4.6 Controller constructor Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, claims-based-identity

When calling `ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("SecuredClass", "GeneralAccess");` in a constructor

```
    public SubmissionsController()
    {            
        try {
            ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("SecuredClass", "GeneralAccess");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When I return false from CheckAccess, it throws as expected a System.Security.SecurityException however immediately it throws a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in System.IdentityModel.Services (mscorlib.dll) As a result this made it difficult to catch the security exception as it was wrapped by the TargetInvocationException.

How can I perform a CheckAccess call in the constructor? (ideally i wanted to put an attribute on the class to ensure the user had general access to the method but also came into odd exceptions as a result)